# Angular: Does Karma have to compile all my code every time I run `ng test`?

Tags: angular, testing, karma-runner

Every time I run `ng test` in my (fairly standard) *Angular 8* project with *Jasmine* and [*Karma*](https://karma-runner.github.io/4.0/index.html), I find that *Karma* builds all of my code before tests start running in the launched browser.

Is there a way for me to tell *Karma* to only build code that has changed from the last time I ran `ng test`? Or some other mechanism for shortening the time between changing my code and seeing the results from my tests with *Karma*?

Comment: Unfortunately, that's how Karma works and that's the main reason why Jest is now recommended.

Comment: @Stefan Do you have a source for this recommendation? Angular default is still Jasmine + Karma in current Angular 11.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Visual Studio Code you could install the "Angular/Karma Test Explorer":
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=raagh.angular-karma-test-explorer

It easily let's you run a single test or a single test file at a time. It is still not super smooth, but it is certainly better and faster than relying on "ng test" and the browser window.